# Importing TXT to excel whilst skipping first 7 characters and moving to the next colomn after each file

Tags: excel, vba

My script is still lacking some functionality. It requires two extra functions:

- Skip the first 7 characters, put the remainder of the line into a cell.
- After completing a txt move 1 column left and go back to row 1

My script is the following:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("F:\Google Drive\IBE project - Heamoscan\Data")

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        ' Open the file
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        ' Read the file one line at a time
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

            ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
            Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
            Next
            i = 0
            ' Move to next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
            
        Loop
        
        Set cl = cl.Offset(0, 1)
        
        ' Clean up
        FileText.Close
    Next file

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use this in your loop?

```
TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

TrimmedLine = Mid(TextLine, 8)

' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
Items = Split(TrimmedLine, "|")
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to have any effect on my output in excel.. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: just updated the 7 to an 8. are your first 7 characters spaces? I would use a msg box before the split to confirm the character count.

Comment: Simon, many thanks for thinking with me on this. However, I decided to use a different software: qlikview. I got a working script in that.